# Migrating an asp.net web app to aws

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I have been asked to help migrate a asp.net app to aws, I havent deployed windows into the cloud before and was interested in getting some pointers ?

Im not worried about the app more about moving the database, its a 200gb mssql db and im wondering about the best way to get it up into the cloud.

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements and budget, this use case might be addressed by [AWS Import/Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/), which is a dedicated offering to accelerate *moving large amounts of data into and out of AWS using portable storage devices for transport*:

> AWS transfers your data directly onto and off of storage devices using
>   Amazon’s high-speed internal network and bypassing the Internet. For
>   significant data sets, AWS Import/Export is often faster than Internet
>   transfer and more cost effective than upgrading your connectivity.

You can gauge the latter via [AWS Import/Export Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/pricing/).

See [Getting Started](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/CHAP_GettingSetUp.html?r=2892) in the [AWS Import/Export Developer Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/Welcome.html?r=6871) for further details.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Well essentially everything is the same as a normal data center. You have a couple options to upload the database. I'm sure there are many more options available as well.

1. Rar the database in multiple peices and upload them in smaller chunks.
2. Utilize S3's new api feature that allows to upload files in parts
3. Create an FTP server and either download the file or upload the file depending on where you create the ftp server.
4. AWS Importer/Export service

If you choose the S3 option, downloading the file from S3 will be extremely fast as S3 is connected to the EC2 network on a gigabit network. You may also want to store backups in S3 as its a fully redundant storage solution so getting your hands dirty using the S3 api might yield results two fold.

If I was performing this task I would choose either the AWS Import/Export or uploading the database to S3.

** Whatever you do... Make sure to compress the file first (unless its AWS Import/Export)